# Primed TNT on summoned mobs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to be able to summon a baby zombie that has a TNT block on its head. 
The command I have so far is

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {IsVillager:0,IsBaby:1,Equipment:[{},{},{},{},     {id:tnt,Count:1}],DropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,0.0F],Attributes: [{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:8},{Name:generic.attackDamage,Base:0}]}
```

However, is there any way to prime that TNT? Im guessing that this would not have anything to do with setting a block over the zombies head, but I do want that for aesthetic value -- and to let the player know the zombie is probably going to blow up.

When doing a little research on the subject before coming here, I came across summoning the TNT at the zombies with a fuse of 0 (zero). For me I don't think that this would work, because the TNT would still not stay with/on the zombie, and would just blow up where it was summoned (killing the zombie in the process most likely. Perhaps there is a way to summon the primedTNT when the baby (summoned with the command above) came with one block of the player? If so this also needs to instantly kill the zombie. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I don't know much about MC Commands, but I found this: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/349889-spawn-lit-tnt-with-command-block

Comment: Basically, primed TNT has a "fuse" property that you need to apply like on the forum.

Answer (score 3):

You can't ignite the TNT in the Zombie's head slot, but you can use the `Passengers` tag to summon the Zombie with `PrimedTnt` riding it.

Example:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~5 {Passengers:[{id:"PrimedTnt", tag:{Fuse:100}}]}
```

Since the Passengers tag is only really a flag that the `/summon` command looks for, `/entitydata` and similar commands won't be able to place a `PrimedTnt` on the `Zombie`. This means that if you want a `PrimedTnt` entity on the `Zombie`,  the only real practical solution is to summon him *with* the TNT.

If you want a proximity trigger, you could summon a `PrimedTnt` with a fuse time of 0 at `Zombie`s near `Player`s.

Example:

```
/execute @e[type=Player] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[type=Zombie,r=1]  ~ ~ ~ summon PrimedTnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:0}
```

We use `@e[type=Player]` instead of `@a` to avoid targeting dead players: we likely don't want a Zombie to explode because it's trying to walk over a corpse.

Comment: Is this in 1.9 only? Or is it compatible with 1.8.8?

Comment: With 1.8.8, you would need to use the `Riding` tag instead of the `Passengers` tag. Instead of summoning a `Zombie` with a `PrimedTNT` as a passenger, you need to summon a `PrimedTNT` riding a `Zombie`. Example: `/summon PrimedTNT ~ ~ ~5 {Fuse:100, Riding:{id:"Zombie"}}`  I don't recommend using this, though, as it is deprecated and will not work in 1.9 or any future versions.

Answer (score 1):

To accurately set the position of the TNT summon it with this command:

```
/summon PrimedTNT ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:NUMBER,CustomName:"NAME"}
```

or

```
/execute @e[type=Zombie] ~ ~ ~ summon PrimedTNT ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:NUMBER,CustomName:"NAME"}
```

with `NUMBER` replaced by a number, and `NAME` replaced by a name of your choice.

If you have more than one zombie in the world, and don't want ALL of them to have the TNT, then give the baby zombie a custom name (eg. `TNTZombie`), and use it in a selector.

Then place a `|repeat|unconditional|always active|` command block with this command:

```
/tp @e[name=NAME] @e[name=TNTZombie]
```

---

In relation to the idea of the "near player" activated aspect, the TNT-summoning command would have to be linked to a `|repeat|unconditional|always active|` command block with a command like this:

```
/execute @e[name=TNTZombie] ~ ~ ~ testfor @a[r=1]
```

Then connect that to a comparator, which will give some delay before activating a `|impulse|unconditional|needs redstone|` command block with this:

```
/execute @e[name=TNTZombie] ~ ~ ~ summon PrimedTNT ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:NUMBER}
```

This system activates the zombie summoning the TNT only *once*. If the explosion somehow doesn't kill the zombie, use a chain command block attached to the previous command block with this command:

```
/kill @e[name=TNTZombie]
```

Have fun with those exploding zombies!